# Setting thin width for columns in ag-Grid not working

Tags: reactjs, width, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am trying to create a thin column in ag-Grid to show buy/sell legend using two different colors. Please see below:

[image]

However even after specifying the width to be `8px`, I am getting a `36px` column. What is the best way to achieve this? I am currently using a `cellClass` function to set the background color and a `valueGetter` function to return a blank value for the cell. Here's the code:

```js
const sideLegendCellClass = (params: CellClassParams) => {
    return [
        params.data.side === 'buy'
            ? classes.buyLegend
            : classes.sellLegend,
    ];
};

const sideLegendValueGetter = () => {
    // return blank string - this cell only renders the buy/sell color
    return '';
};

<AgGridColumn
    field="side"
    headerName=""
    width={8}
    cellClass={sideLegendCellClass}
    valueGetter={sideLegendValueGetter}
/>
```

Full code is [here](https://github.com/nareshbhatia/trade-force/blob/master/trade-force-client/src/components/Orders/Orders.tsx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting both `width` and `minWidth` to `8`

```js
<AgGridColumn minWidth={8} width={8} />
```

There are 2 things I want to address in your code. Firstly, if you don't want to display the value in your column (for example, when making a toolbar or in your case, display legend color), simply leave `field` `undefined`, you don't need to set `valueGetter: () => ''`.

Another thing is that you can return a string in `cellClass` if you only have one class name.

```js
const sideLegendCellClass = (params: CellClassParams) => {
    return params.data.side === 'buy' ? classes.buyLegend : classes.sellLegend;
};

<AgGridColumn
    width={8}
    minWidth={8}
    cellClass={sideLegendCellClass}
    // since the width is too small you should remove the padding
    // or the legend cell will be overlapped with the next cell
    cellStyle={{ padding: 0 }}
/>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 64191347/setting-thin-width-for-columns-in-ag-grid-not-working]

Comment: Not related but I'm very disappointed about the new syntax highlighting. it looks horrendous and nothing like the code in my IDE!

Comment: Once again, thank you so much for your help, Near! The UI has the final finish that I was looking for. Please take a look at the snapshot [here](https://github.com/nareshbhatia/trade-force). Only thing left for me now is to implement server-side row model!